# UserString subclass, 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

I'm kinda stuck at this code, it's supposed to create a string-like object, which, upon using, will return internal lambda's value. I use collections.UserString.

```
from collections import UserString
class instrx(UserString):
    func = None
    data = ''
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.func = func
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        print("get",name)
        if name=='data':
            self.data = self.func()
        return UserString.__getattribute__(self,name)
a = instrx(lambda: 'aa')
print(a,type(a))
print(a.lower())
```

Running this code gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\a.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(a.lower())
  File "C:\Python35\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 1082, in __str__
    def __str__(self): return str(self.data)
  File "C:\path\a.py", line 10, in __getattribute__
    self.data = self.func()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Python version: 3.4, 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured this out.
It seems that in some functions in UserString (like `.lower()` in example) `self.__class__(self.data)` construction is used. I did a little workaround:

```
import time
from collections import UserString
class instrx(UserString):
    func = None
    data = ''
    def __init__(self,data,func=None):
        self.data = data
        if func==None:
            self.func = lambda: UserString.__getattribute__(self,'data')
        else:
            self.func = func
    def __getattribute__(self,name):
        if name=='data':
            self.data = str(self.func())
        return UserString.__getattribute__(self,name)
a = instrx('',func=lambda: time.time())
print(a,type(a))
print(a.lower())
print(a+"test")
```

Works just fine.